# Debug nodejs app in CF

Tags: node.js, ssh, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I follow this guide how to debug node.js application in CF and its currently not working ,

https://medium.com/@KevinHoffman/debugging-node-js-applications-in-cloud-foundry-b8fee5178a09#.ekkzo3f63

I've installed the node inspector and I see message in the logs like:

```
2017-03-23T15:29:21.58+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0]ERR Debugger listening on [::]:5858
```

I did the ssh command

Now what should I do ?
in the guide it says the following after the ssh

1. `export PATH=$PATH:/app/.heroku/node/bin`

what should be .heroku  ? I'm not running in heroku ...
**So how which path I should provide ?**

2.when I run the following command in `/app/node_modules/.bin`

```
./node-inspector --web-port=9090
```

**I got error: ** 
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
any idea ? I guess it's related to the first issue...

We are working on CF version 2.74

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs...

> If you want the environment of your interactive SSH session to match the environment of your buildpack-based app, with the same environment variables and working directory, run the following commands after starting the session:

```
export HOME=/home/vcap/app
export TMPDIR=/home/vcap/tmp
cd /home/vcap/app
[ -d /home/vcap/app/.profile.d ] && for f in /home/vcap/app/.profile.d/*.sh; do source "$f"; done
source /home/vcap/app/.profile
```

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html#ssh-env

These instructions are generic though, for the Node.js build pack you could simply run `HOME=/home/vcap/app source $HOME/app/.profile.d/nodejs.sh` since there's only one file to source from the build pack.  Then optionally source the `.profile`, if your app has one and you need / want to include it.

Also, as the docs mention you should take a look through all `.profile` and `.profile.d/*.sh` scripts before running them to make sure there are no unintended side effects.

**UPDATE:**

A slightly easier way to do this is to run `cf ssh myapp -t -c "/tmp/lifecycle/launcher /home/vcap/app bash ''"`.  This will open a bash shell and it lets the lifecycle launcher handle sourcing & setting up the environment.

Comment: HI Daniel , I got error when try to run:HOME=/home/vcap/app source $HOME/app/.profile.d/nodejs.sh the error is: bash: /home/vcap/app/app/.profile.d/nodejs.sh: No such file or directory

Comment: You have `app` in your path twice, `/home/vcap/app/app/.profile.d/nodejs.sh`.  Remove one of the `app/`'s.  Probably means $HOME is already set to `/home/vcap/app`.  So you could just run `source $HOME/app/.profile.d/nodejs.sh`.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to read this piece of the [Bluemix documentation on Application Management](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/app_mng.html#app_management). It has sections for `Liberty` and `Node.js` apps. For Node.js it explains how to enable the inspector.

For the specific question: The `node` executable that you are looking for is under `/app/vendor/node/bin`. So the command would be:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/app/vendor/node/bin
```

Comment: so what should I put in the path , can you please give example export PATH=$PATH:/app/.heroku/node/bin ?

Comment: I added it to the answer

Comment: THanks, I've tried with  export PATH=$PATH:/app/vendor/node/bin and when I got to  cd /app/node_modules/.bin and run  ./node-inspector --web-port=9090 ,I got error: /usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory