# Cloud Foundry: How to get debug/trace logs in Node.js applications

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-watson

We have deployed Node.js application in IBM Cloud with Cloud Foundry. We are able to see the standard logs of the application in logs tab. We need to enable trace/debug the cloud application and check the logs but we are not able to set the logs to trace/debug for the application.

How we can achieve this, i.e., see debug output of a Node.js app?

Comment: How does this apply to Watson Assistant? Are you trying to debug a Node.js app and would like more diagnostics?

Comment: @data_henrik, yes, we need to debug node js application.
its not related to watson assistant, removed the group .

Comment: Would that work for you? https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/debugging-nodejs-applications/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Debug nodejs app in CF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978007/debug-nodejs-app-in-cf)

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42978007/debug-nodejs-app-in-cf

Comment: @data_henrik, thanks for sharing the links, we will go through the links.